# Comparison test for convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

One of the ways to check a series convergence is the comparison test. Maybe I'm just missing something basic, but $\frac1x<\frac1{x^2}$ The infinite series of $\frac1{x^2}$ converges but the one for $\frac1x$ does not. Is this an exception or am I making a mistake?

Comment: $\frac12 < \frac14$?

Comment: @peterwhy - thanks:) sometimes we just need reminders of the basics:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that $\frac 1 n <\frac 1 {n^{2}}$. The reverse inequality is true.